# error MSB3073: The command "subwcrev.exe exited with code 6. Running MSBuild on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build, msbuild, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to do a build with MSBuild plugin in Jenkins. I have successfully installed and configured the MSBuild plugin. Completed config. The Build part is successfull, MsBuild installation is done correctly too. When trying to run the build command from GUI, however, this is seen:

```
SubWCRev : E155036: The working copy at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\FolderName'
18:05:15   is too old (format 8) to work with client version '1.9.7 (r1800392)' (expects format 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first.
18:05:15   
18:05:15 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1063,5): error MSB3073: **The command "subwcrev.exe** "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\FolderName\." "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\IropsAnalyzer\Tools\SomeFoldername\Repository\SomeFolder.Repository\Properties\AssemblyInfo.template" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\IropsAnalyzer\Tools\LegalitiesAnalyzer\Repository\LegalitiesAnalyzer.Repository\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"" **exited with code 6**. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\FolderName\Tools\SomeFolderName\Repository\SomeFolderName.Repository\SomeFolderName.Repository.csproj]
```

In order to counter the need to upgrade the working copy issue I selected the version to 1.9 which is highest there is, still get the same issue. Also, looked up on exit code 6 but not much available. Any pointers?

Comment: 6 means "SVN error: Subversion returned with an error when SubWCRev tried to find the information from the working copy.". Cannot test it now, but maybe this means it's not a working copy? Try running the command manually in the repository to see what happens?

Comment: So when I try to manually run the command through visual studio command prompt the build compiles. I came to Jenkins after testing the MSBuild command after testing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

stijn's comment lead me in the right direction.

I'm using the Tortoise SVN client. When I browse to my project in folder explorer and right click, I get the option "SVN Upgrade working copy". My repository was using an older format (less than 1.8).